# Add custom RSS feed tags in AEM

Tags: rss, aem, feed, atom-feed

I'm trying to add custom **atom:tags** for RSS feed in AEM.

I've overridden OOTB code to `/apps/cq/Page/feed.jsp` from equivalent `libs` path.

I'm able to extract the image path from the `jcr-node`, but not able to add it to the custom tag successfully.

How to add a custom tags in the taglibs for the prefix **atom**?

Imports

```html
    --%><%@ page session="false" %><%

        %><%@ page import="com.day.cq.commons.Externalizer,
                           com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page,
                           com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode,
                           java.util.Iterator,
                           javax.jcr.Node,
                           com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext" %><%
        %><%@ taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0" %><%
        %><%@ taglib prefix="cq" uri="http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/1.0" %><%
        %><%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %><%
        %><%@ taglib prefix="atom" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/atom/1.0" %><%
        %><cq:defineObjects /><%
```

Custom code

```java
    Node jcrNode = currentNode.hasNode("jcr:content") ? currentNode.getNode("jcr:content") : null;
            Node imageNode = jcrNode != null && jcrNode.hasNode("image") ? jcrNode.getNode("image") : null;
            String image = imageNode != null && imageNode.hasProperty("fileReference") ?
                    imageNode.getProperty("fileReference").getValue().getString() : null;

            %><atom:feed id="<%= url %>"><%
                %><atom:title><c:out value="<%= title %>"/></atom:title><%
                if (subTitle != null) {
                    %><atom:subtitle><c:out value="<%= subTitle %>"/></atom:subtitle><%
                }
                if (image != null) {
                    %><atom:image><c:out value="<%= image %>"/></atom:image><%
                }
            %><atom:link href="<%= link %>" rel="self"/><%
```

Image tag is not identified

```html
    <atom:image></atom:image>
```

Error logs

```sh
    .feed HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
    org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/cq/Page/feed.jsp(60,18) No tag "image" defined in tag library imported with prefix "atom"
```

Answer (score 0):

`atom:image` is not part of the Atom syndication format. See [The Atom Syndication Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287). Take a look at `atom:icon` or `atom:logo`.